What does CMAKE_SYSROOT need to be for cross-compilation?
New to cross-compiling--
I'm trying to cross-compile a C API to ARM using the vivado 2016.4 SDK.
The target env (filesystem tree) for this C project does not contain stdint.h
Does it need to?
In my toolchain file, when I set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/my-sysroot/"), the build fails due to not being able to find stdint.h
If I instead set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/app/tools/xilinx/vivado2016.4/SDK/2016.4/gnu/arm/lin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/libc/") then the build succeeds.
I am assuming that this SYSROOT value is okay, as the issue concerns a standard library header?
Further on in the toolchain file, I have
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /my-sysroot/ 
                      /my-sysroot//usr/lib)

Is CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH intended for linking to libs outside of standard C?
Thanks!
